# Permanent SFTP Connection between two linux servers

Tags: linux, sftp

i have two CentOS Servers

One has application for manage printing templates
Another contain app which is take files from hotfolder and send them to the printer

How i can set up permanent sftp connection between this two servsers?
Or may be you can suggest something better?

Comment: Why not use SAMBA or NFS for the "hotfolder"?

Answer (score 3):

You could have one of the machines act as an SSH server (you'll need to install OpenSSH or the like for that) and then mount it from the other one via sshfs. To make the mountpoint "permanent" (persistent across reboots) you can use public-private key authentication (so that there's no need to enter a password) and write a script to run the sshfs command from the client for you at startup.

Comment: Indeed, you don't need sftp, that requires either human interactivity or some kind of script to poll & control the client session. Or you use SCP or rsync+ssh to copy the new files to the 2nd server.